# GCP: How to start preemptible VM instance (with preemptible GPU)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

First timer in GCP and already spent more than an hour trying to figure out how I should  create following from GCP console (online web page)

1. Preemptible Compute Engine,
2. Associate preemptibe GPU with above compute engine.

I reviewed [How to specify preemptible GPU Deep Learning Virtual Machine on GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52769663/how-to-specify-preemptible-gpu-deep-learning-virtual-machine-on-gcp), but I want to start from GCP console (website)

Also, I reviewed https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-preemptible-instance, but I don't see "Availability policy" under ComputeEngine -> VM Instances -> Create (this give a page "create an instance", but there is no option for 'availability policy')

Also, I reviewed https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible for creating managed instance group (and then chose template), but I don't see 'availability policy' there also.

It should not be that hard and I may be missing obvious thing. How will I create preemptible compute engine and add preemptible GPU to this computing engine

Answer (score 2):

Go to Create an instance. You need to select a Machine Type of `n1-standard-n` or larger. Shared-core machine types are not supported for GPUs. Then scroll down to "Management, security, disks, ..." and expand this option. You will now find Availability policy so that you can select Preemptibility.